# What is difference between BoxBufferGeometry vs BoxGeometry in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, animation, three.js, jquery-animate

I am learning Three.js. I can't find a proper answer about the difference between BoxBufferGeometry vs BoxGeometry. Help me.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`[Primitive]Geometry` classes are manipulation friendly, memory unfriendly all JS geometry classes.

What this means that each piece of data that defines this geometry is stored as an instance of some class (`Vector3`,`Vector2`,`Face3`) etc. These come with convenience methods, so you can dot a vertex with some other vector, translate vertices, modify uvs, modify normals and such. But it has overhead in memory and performance (creating all these instances, storing them).

`[Primitive]BufferGeometry` classes are performance friendly geometry classes that rely on typed arrays to store the data in a WebGL friendly format.

What this means that vertices, instead of being an array of `Vector3`s are typed arrays:

```
Array[v0,v1... vN]
vs:
Float32Array[v0x,v0y,v0z,v1x,v1y,v1z... vNx,vNy,vNz]
```

They are much more efficient to store but much harder to manipulate.

If you want to modify a vertex:

With `Geometry`

```
//with Geometry you just get vertex 5 and have access to it's x...
//AND the methods of the class -> Vector3.add(Vector3)
myGeom.vertices[5].add(new THREE.Vector3(1,2,3))
```

With `BufferGeometry`

```
//xyz are just numbers, so with a stride of 3
//we select x , and  then the next two for y and z
//we have to know that the 15th number in this array is x of vertex 5...
const stride = 3
const index = 5
let offset = index * stride
myGeom.attributes.position.array[offset++] += 1 
myGeom.attributes.position.array[offset++] += 2 
myGeom.attributes.position.array[offset  ] += 3
```

**However**

`THREE.BufferAttribute` does have several methods to write and read stuff from that array. It is still a lot more verbose:

```
//add x: 1 y: 2 z: 3 to 5th vertex

const index = 5
const attribute = myGeometry.attributes.position
const v3add = new THREE.Vector3(1,2,3)

attribute.setXYZ( 
  index, 
  attribute.getX(index) + v3add.x,
  attribute.getY(index) + v3add.y,
  attribute.getZ(index) + v3add.z
)
```

Comment: While easier to read, I'm inclined to say the `BufferGeometry` change example is incorrect. **1)** The vertices for a standard `[Primitive]BufferGeometry` object are stored in `myGeom.attributes.position`. There is no `vertices` property unless you're adding a custom attribute for a custom shader. **2)** You can still get and set the values by index, it's just a little more verbose. `var pos = myGeom.attributes.position; pos.setXYZ(5, pos.getX(5) + 1, pos.getY(5) + 2, pos.getZ(5) + 3);`.

Comment: This answer has multiple errors, and @pailhead knows better.

Comment: Please edit it, this was mostly just pseudo code, `add(1,2,3)` also doesn't make sense.

Comment: The idea was to explain the difference conceptually, not give exact names and properties. The important concept here was the array itself, not really where it lives, but i've edited the answer.